# Strange behaviour with Dart asynchronous tests

Tags: testing, asynchronous, dart

Why doesn't this work?

```dart
var validUri = 'postgresql://user:pwd@localhost:5432/testdb';

test('Query on closed connection.', () {
  connect(validUri).then((conn) {
    conn.close();
    conn.query("select 'blah'").toList()
      .then((_) => throw new Exception('Should not be reached.'))
      .catchError(expectAsync1((err) {}));
  });
});

test('Execute on closed connection.', () {
  connect(validUri).then((conn) {
    conn.close();
    conn.execute("select 'blah'")
      .then((_) => throw new Exception('Should not be reached.'))
      .catchError(expectAsync1((err) {});
  });
});
```

But, if one changes the callback assignment for the last *catchError*:

```dart
(...)

test('Execute on closed connection.', () {
  var cb = expectAsync1((e) {});
  connect(validUri).then((conn) {
    conn.close();
    conn.execute("select 'blah'")
      .then((_) => throw new Exception('Should not be reached.'))
      .catchError(cb);
  });
});
```

It works!

I would love to read a nice explanation on this and perhaps have a lesson or two in Dart asynchronous testing :-)

Edit:
The problem is that the first example did work - it reported passing! It shouldn't have. I assume expectAsyncX() must have been called back during a later test.

Is this a problem with the test framework? This type of problem shouldn't be silently ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any asynchronous call should be wrapped with expectAsyncX() telling the test to wait for its call.
In your first case, your first async call is not wrapped, so it doesn't "wait" enough to execute the expectAsync1 in the catchError.

Comment: So, wrapping is as easy as *var cb = expectAsync1((e) {});*?

Comment: yes. There also ways to specify how often the callback should be executed, but it shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks Guillaume and @FlorianLoitsch!

Comment: I think you might find this helpful: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#asynchronous-tests

Comment: The problem is it's really easy to accidentally call expectAsyncX(), after test() has completed. In my case, I had a bug in my test suite, that still reported passing, even though it wasn't working. The expectAsyncX(), must have called back during another test case. See [here](https://github.com/xxgreg/postgresql/commit/e4738a0f7b66e6db1ca421540179e45a82c62e52).

Comment: Damn - my 5min edit window ran out. Edited: The problem is that the first example did work - it reported passing! It shouldn't have. It's really easy to accidentally call expectAsyncX() after test() has completed. This bug in my test suite always passed. I must have run it hundreds of times, even though it wasn't working. The expectAsyncX(), must have called back during another test case. Any ideas how to improve the test so that it would actually report a fail in the first case?